# Stop Codesandbox from auto-updating the preview on file change

Tags: codesandbox

How can I make Codesandbox stop updating the browser preview while I type?

I turned off ***auto save*** in VS Code, but still Codesandbox updates the preview pane instantly, all the time, showing long lists of syntax errors while I'm working on the code.

Answer (score 4):

1. Click **top-left Icon**
2. `File` > `Preferences` > `CodeSandbox Settings`
3. In the Dialog click the `Preview` tab (in the left side pane)
4. Uncheck `Preview on edit`

[image]
[image]

It's funny the dialog's name is very inconsistent with the menu item's name which had opened it.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I finally discovered the Preferences item on the right. Same icon as Configuration item on the left. That may have caused the confusion...

Comment: The menu to toggle this can currently be found in the top left corner by clicking  File>Preferences>CodeSandbox Settings>Preview.
Or in the top right corner by clicking Preferences>Preview.